# HTML5 FileReader each loop crashes browser - Optimize For Large Directories

Tags: jquery, html, loops, filesystems, filereader

I have a code that gets a user's local directory and then opens a filereader object for each mp3 file it finds in the directory.  Sometimes this can be over 1,000 files.  How would I optimize this code so that it does not crash the browser?  It works perfectly for directories with up to 200-300 files in it, but crashes the browser without any errors in the console log.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
Here is the link to a jsFiddle page of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/X6BZe/

The filecount variable is used to try and split the files into groups of 10 and spread them apart with the settimeout function, but that does not seem to be very effective.  I tried it without it still crashed the browser.

Here is the main part of my code, the rest of it is just the jDataView code helping to retrieve the ID3 tags.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#file-input").on("change", function(e){
var thefiles = e.target.files;
var filecount = 0;
$.each(thefiles, function(i, item){
    if(item.type == "audio/mp3"){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() {
            var dv = new jDataView(this.result);
            if (dv.getString(3, dv.byteLength - 128) == 'TAG') {
                var title = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
                var artist = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
                var album = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
                var year = dv.getString(4, dv.tell());
                $("#thelist").append(title + " - " + artist + " - " + album + " - " + year + "<br />");
            } 
            else {// no ID3v1 data found.
                var title = "????";
                var artist = "????";
                var album = "????";
                var year = "????";
            }
            dv = "";
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(thefile);
    }
    filecount += 1;
    if(filecount == 10){
        setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);         
        filecount = 0;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the sheer number of files you end up having open and reading...

when I refactor it (see below for pretty ugly code, but with a bunch of console logging so you can watch what happens) so that rather than trying to blast through and open FileReaders for the whole array it processes sequentially while it's a *lot* slower than you'd probably want (because it has to read each file to get at the ID3 tags at the end) it doesn't crash (I also set the dv and filereader to "" after processing... not sure if it helps with memory management but seemed to keep the chrome allocation going up quite as high).

You may be able to improve throughput over a sequential solution by managing the number of FileReaders you keep open (say have a pool of *n* readers and as soon as one is finished feed it the next item in the list and experiment to find the tradeoff between number of connections, throughput and stability

there's probably more elegant solutions ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#file-input").on("change", function(e){
    var thefiles = e.target.files;

  var i = 0;

  //    $.each(thefiles, function(i, item){
//      var thefile = item;

console.log("Start process");
process(i);
console.log("------> All Done <---------");

function process(wf) {
    thefile = thefiles[wf];
        if (thefile.type == "audio/mp3") {
            console.log("Read " + thefile.name + " " + thefile.type);

            var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function() {
                    console.log("********** Processing ");
                var dv = new jDataView(this.result);
                if (dv.getString(3, dv.byteLength - 128) == 'TAG') {
                    var title = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
                    var artist = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
                    var album = dv.getString(30, dv.tell());
                    var year = dv.getString(4, dv.tell());
                    $("#thelist").append(title + " - " + artist + " - " + album + " - " + year + "<br />");
                } 
                else {// no ID3v1 data found.
                    var title = "????";
                    var artist = "????";
                    var album = "????";
                    var year = "????";
                }
                dv = "";
                reader = "";
                console.log("Processed");
                    i++
                            if (i<thefiles.length) {
                    process(i);
                } else {
                    return
                }
            }

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(thefile);
        } else {
            console.log("Skip " + thefile.name + " " + thefile.type);
                i++
                             if (i<thefiles.length) {

                              process(i);
                } else {
                    return
                }
        }


  } // end of process

//  });
});
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I'm doing and the scripts running faster than I thought it ever would. THANKS!